0 self intersection and dimension of canonical image
Let $S$ be a smooth complex projective surface (and also integral).
I suppose the canonical divisor $K$ verifies $K^{2} = 0$. One can show for every $n \ge 1$, the canonical divisor $|nK| $ has a mobile part $M$ such that $M^{2} = 0$. In the book of Beauville on complex algebraic surfaces, the author claims that this implies the $dim(\phi_{nK}(S)) \leq 1$ where $\phi_{nK} : S --> \mathbb{P}^{|nK|}_{\mathbb{C}}$ is the canonical rational map associated to $nK$.
Could you please explain me how? We can suppose $S$ is minimal in the sense of Definition $II.15$ of the book of Beauville.
Many thanks in advance.

In Positivity in algebraic Geometry, section 2, 2.2, you can find the defintion of a Big divisor, which tell us that a divisor $D$ on a variety $X$ such that $\max\{\operatorname{dim}(\phi_{nD}(X))\}=\operatorname{dim}(X)$ is called big. There is a Characterization of big divisors, in particular, it say that we can find an ample divisor $L$ and an unique $m>0$ such that $mD\sim L+N$, where $N$ is an efective divisor. So, under your hyphothesis, if $K_S$ is big, and so $0=m^2K_S^2=(L+N)^2>0$. It makes a contradiction, therefore, $\operatorname{dim}(\phi_{nK_S}(S))\leq 1$  for any $n$.

Hi, many thanks for this answer. But how do you know that $(L+N)^{2} > 0$? Indeed $L^{2} + 2N.L > 0$ by Nakaï-Moishezon but what about $N^{2}$? Sorry if I miss something obvious but I do not master the intersection theory very well...

Hi, since $N$ is Nef $N^2\geq$, see for example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63999/nef-divisor-on-surface

Oh Ok. It's great! I think of it while eating : could we argue differently bu saying their is no curve with self intersection $< 0$ by minimality of $S$ ? Hence their are no effective divisor with self intersection $< 0$?

Hi, suppose that $X$ is K3 surface, which is minimal because if $C\cong \mathbb{P}^1$ has $C^2=-1$, then by genus formula $-2=2g(C)-2=C^2$, which is a contradiction. Nevertheless, on a K3 surface $X$ could exists $-2$-curves. Indeed,  if $X$ is the double cover of $Bl_{1pt}(\mathbb{P}^2)$ with branch locus a smooth curve $C\in |6L^*-2E|$, then the preimage of $E$ on $X$ is a $-2$-curve. Therefore, minimality does not implies that there are not curves with negative intersection.

OK. But, why is N nef? (in this sense https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nef_line_bundle)? I read the section Positivity in algebraic geometry and the N is just effective?

If we assume that $X$ is minimal, $K_X$ is nef, and if we supposse that $\operatorname{dim}(\phi_{nK_X}(X))=2$ for some $n$, then $K_X$ is big and nef, Theorem 2.2.14 (Bigness of nef divisor) on Positivity on Alegbraic Geometry 1, say that $K_X^2>0$.

So you are using another argument here? (this doesn't prove $N$ could be chosen  nef).  But it works! For the proof of $K_{X}$ nef, one can refer to Example 1.4.18. page 58 of the book mentioned above.

Yes, N could be not nef and as you remark it is only effective, but $m^2K^2=mK(L+N)=m(KL+KN)>0$ By Kleiman.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
